# Flashlight blink on button click in android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a flashlight application in which I am trying to add blink functionality on button click. The code that i found for this is:

```
String myString = "0101010101";
long blinkDelay 50; //Delay in ms
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
   if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
      params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
   } else {
      params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
   }
   try {
      Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

But this code turns off flashlight after few blinks. How can i start flashlight blink on button click and stop it unless I click it again? Any Help?

Comment: Ditch the `String`, use an infinite loop, add a listener for the button click and a flag that will set your loop to break, then turn it off one last time after breaking.

Comment: I have tried infinite loop but then app gets freezed. I was not able to break the loop on button click

Comment: Avoid the thread.sleep in the UI thread.

Comment: This is a very odd way of alternating between 2 pre-defined states - form a string of 0s and 1s : then iterate the string calling a method to extract each character : then compare that character to 0 or 1 to decide if light is on or off... Usually you would just use some sort of boolean and just flip it `myBool = !myBool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You will have to use a **separate thread** to prevent UI freeze.
- Thread will contain a **while loop** which will allow it to blink continuously.
- To break the loop on button click use a **boolean variable** in while condition.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's controlled by your string length so the for loop will break after the count of i becomes greater than last index. 
Use a while loop if you want to blink the flash continuously. 
You can use one boolean variable to switch between on off. 
And a boolean in while condition to break the loop when button is clicked

Comment: Do you mean to say use a while loop?

Comment: Yes a while loop

Answer (score 0):

*You will have to use a thread to prevent UI freeze.*
*Thread will contain a while loop which will allow it to blink continuously.*

```
 while (shouldGlow ) {
          flashLight();
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

  }
```

//use boolean varibale to stop the loop